# Sinon stubbing a function passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon, stub

I have the following Example class:

```
function Example() {...}
Example.prototype.someFunc1() {...}
Example.prototype.someFunc2() {...}
Example.prototype.func(func) {var res = func(); ...}
```

I usually call `Example#func()` as follows:

```
var example = new Example();
example.func(example.someFunc1)
// or like this, depending on what I want
example.func(example.someFunc2)
```

Now I stub `Example#someFunc1()` as follows in my test:

```
var example = new Example();
sinon.stub(example, 'someFunc1').returns(...);
exmaple.func(example.someFunc1);
```

Problem is that `Example#someFunc1()` is not being stubbed this way and being called normally. What can I do in such situation ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/a2b786fd485b6767606bcb20942c4616

Comment: @DaveNewton I made a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/f7p7z5fL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you save a reference to the function. Then you stub it.

You're passing a reference to the original function, not the stubbed function.

The function you stub does not disappear when you stub it–that's why you can `restore()` it later. You either need to pass a reference to object's function itself, e.g.,

```
sinon.stub(example, 'opt1').returns(42);
example.logic([3, 2], example.opt1);
```

Or pass a reference to the stub, e.g.,

```
var fn = sinon.stub(example, 'opt1').returns(42);
example.logic([3, 2], fn);
```

The latter doesn't really make any sense as a test, though; you could just pass in any function, there's no reason to stub anything.

FWIW, your fiddle is nowhere near equivalent to the original code you posted.

---

It's unclear what you're trying to test: you pass a function reference–this could be any old function, whether or not it's attached to the `Example` object, e.g., an anonymous function would be fine.

If the function under test *itself* called the stubbed function, stubbing makes sense.

Comment: Yea, I didn't know what I was thinking I just wanted to unit-test #logic() and isolate it, so I stubbed it, I should've just passed any stub like you said.. thanks :)